# What happened to the natural armor and spell resistance of the Mythic subtype in Mythic Adventures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, errata, mythic-adventures

What happened to the natural armor and spell resistance of the [Mythic Subtype](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/Creature-types/#Mythic_Subtype) in Mythic Adventures?

> - Natural armor increase equal to its Mythic Rank.
> - Spell resistance increase (if it has spell resistance) equal to its Mythic Rank.

I can't find these referenced anywhere in the Mythic rulebook. Were they dropped? Is there errata for them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### They're in the rulebook?

Page 226 of my copy of Mythic Adventures has them listed in it. For reference, here's the subtype after being copied and pasted (italics mine).

> #### MYTHIC SUBTYPE
>
> A creature with this subtype is infused with mythic power and is capable of terrible and awe-inspiring feats. Creatures with the mythic subtype gain the following abilities.
>
> **Mythic Rank**: A creature with the mythic subtype gains 1 to 10 mythic ranks, representing its overall mythic power. Its rank is generally equal to 1/2 its original CR.
>
> ***Natural Armor Bonus**: Add the creature’s mythic rank to its natural armor bonus. A creature without natural armor has an effective natural armor bonus of +0.*
>
> **Bonus Hit Points**: A creature with d6 Hit Dice gains 6 hit points per mythic rank, a creature with d8 Hit Dice gains 8 hit points per
> rank, and a creature with d10 or d12 Hit Dice gains 10 hit points per
> rank. Note that this is the same number of bonus hit points the
> creature would gain if it had a mythic simple template (as described
> in the sidebar on page 225).
>
> **Damage Reduction**: A creature with 5 to 10 Hit Dice gains DR 5/epic. A creature with 11 or more Hit Dice gains DR 10/epic.
>
> If the creature already has damage reduction, it adds epic to the
> qualities needed to bypass that reduction. If the damage reduction
> granted from this subtype has a larger numerical value than the
> creature’s original damage reduction, increase the creature’s original
> damage reduction to the amount of the epic DR. For example, a monster
> with DR 5/bludgeoning that gains DR 10/epic from the mythic subtype
> gains DR 10/bludgeoning and epic.
>
> ***Spell Resistance**: If the creature has spell resistance, add its mythic rank to its spell resistance.*
>
> **Mythic Power**: The creature gains the mythic power and surge universal monster abilities (see pages 227 and 228). The monster’s
> surge die depends on its rank, as summarized in Table 6–5: Mythic
> Subtype Abilities.
>
> **Ability Bonus**: At 2nd rank and every 2 ranks thereafter, the monster gains a permanent +2 bonus to an ability score. If it has
> multiple bonuses, it can apply them to the same ability score or to
> different ability scores.
>
> **Mythic Feats**: At 1st rank and every 2 ranks thereafter, the monster gains a mythic feat. It must meet all of the prerequisites for
> this feat.
>
> **Additional Mythic Abilities**: The monster gains a number of mythic abilities equal to its MR + 1. Such abilities can be drawn from the
> mythic path abilities in Chapter 1 or the mythic abilities listed with
> the monsters in this chapter, or it can be a new ability you create by
> taking inspiration from those abilities. These abilities should be
> thematically appropriate for the creature.
>
> Some new monster abilities are especially powerful; at the GM’s
> discretion, they can count as two abilities toward this total. For
> example, the mythic fire giant’s fire vortex ability could count as
> two mythic abilities (see page 199).
>
> In place of a mythic ability, the monster may gain a universal
> monster ability, such as rend or pounce, either from an existing
> Bestiary or from this book.
>
> **CR**: When you’re finished adding abilities to the monster, add
> 1/2 the monster’s mythic rank to its CR to determine its new CR.
> Evaluate the monster at its new CR using Table 6–8: Monster Statistics
> by CR to make sure it falls within the expected values for its new CR.
>
> **XP**: Change the creature’s XP award to match its new CR (Core
> Rulebook 398).

Even on AoN the [subtype](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterSubtypes.aspx?ItemName=Mythic) has them listed.

Comment: It's very odd to hide that under Monster templates and never mention it in all the Base Mythic Abilities where a player would look rather than a GM. However, thanks for pointing to the exact spot.

Comment: That's because it's for monsters with the Mythic subtype, which players do not count as. @niekell

Comment: Mythic PCs are denied things which are available to Mythic NPCs? That hardly seems fair or balanced! Why shouldn't Mythic PCs be given the Mythic subtype, a bunch of abilities and magic pretty much rely on 'mythic sources' and 'mythic targets'?

Comment: @niekell because they're not mythic monsters? Anything with mythic ranks (monsters) or mythic tiers (pcs/npcs) counts as a mythic creature for the purpose of spells, abilities, and magic items, however counting as a mythic creature, and having the mythic subtype are 2 different things.

Comment: Similarly, creatures with the mythic subtype don't gain the abilities of the mythic progression that is granted to players for their tiers. E.G. Hard to kill, Amazing Initiative, recuperation, unstoppable, immortal, etc.

Comment: Thanks @willuwontu, for restoring the balance to my view. Subtypes get one set of abilities (which closely mirrors what PCs get) but PCs get Tiers. That seems fair as I'd expect PCs to do more to earn more. All good now thanks again.